# MYSQL Query Language

Tags: mysql

```
select max(total),blockfloor 
from 
    (select blockfloor,count(roomnumber) as total 
    from room 
    where unavailable='0'  
    group by blockfloor) x;
```

Above code is mysql query which I used to find the blockfloor, which has maximum number of rooms available.I don't have clear understand about roll of x here.Can anyone explain what is the roll of x?

Comment: The subquery aliased to x isn't needed. Use a query with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses. i.e. the maximum is the first on the list if sorted by the total in decending order.

Comment: Try it without x. Incidentally, the query is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

In your sql query x is alias for the temp table, where will be data from subquery.
for find max total row, you can use query

```
select blockfloor,count(roomnumber) as total 
from room 
where unavailable='0' 
group by blockfloor
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

where you order rows by total, and get first row with max value.